# How can I understand the different types of r-squared from the felm function of the lfe package in R?

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, r-squared

I'm interested in extracting different types of (adjusted) R^2 from a panel model with time fixed and individual fixed effects, that is:

1. The overall $R^2$
2. The within $R^2$
3. The between $R^2$

(For an explanation, see [Interpretation of $R^2$ in fixed-effects panel regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79723/interpretation-of-r2-in-fixed-effects-panel-regression).) I'm using the `felm` function from the `lfe` package in R. The `summary` function gives me two values of $R^2$: The full model and the projection model, but I'm not really sure how to interpret them.

```
Call:
   felm(formula = dynmes ~ treat + ban + treat.ban + log(total.assets) +      
                  market.to.book + leverage | symbol + date, 
                  data = all_200d_balanced) 

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.32605 -0.01682 -0.00116  0.01388  1.23264 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
treatTRUE                 NA         NA      NA       NA    
banTRUE                   NA         NA      NA       NA    
treat.banTRUE      9.015e-03  7.390e-04  12.199  < 2e-16 ***
log(total.assets) -5.283e-03  6.459e-04  -8.179 2.86e-16 ***
market.to.book    -1.523e-03  5.598e-05 -27.211  < 2e-16 ***
leverage           9.938e-04  1.165e-05  85.295  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03594 on 281237 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared(full model): 0.7373   Adjusted R-squared: 0.7365 
Multiple R-squared(proj model): 0.02792   Adjusted R-squared: 0.02494 
F-statistic(full model):915.8 on 862 and 281237 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16 
F-statistic(proj model): 36.25 on 6 and 281237 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

(I found the related question, [What does it mean for Multiple "R-squared(proj model)" in felm, package lfe](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146431/what-does-it-mean-for-multiple-r-squaredproj-model-in-felm-package-lfe), interesting, but the answer does not explain $R^2$.)

I want to know:

1. How I can extract the $R^2$s listed above, and
2. how these are related to the $R^2$s given by the `summary` function?

Comment: The question about how to extract them is off topic here, but the question about how to understand them is OK. You may not get an answer to the former.

Answer (score 2):

here is a quick interpretation- 
overall r squared- the total amount of variance explained by your model
within r squared- the total amount of variance explained by your conditional predictors (your random effects)
between r squared- the total amount of variance explained by your nominal predictors (your fixed effects)

1. This is an extremely debated topic within statistics. Different scholars will tell you different things. The usual way of approaching this is to examine the variance components. A really quick way to interpret this is compared the variance explained by a conditional predictor with the remaining random variance.
2. within + between = total, if I understand your question correctly

How to extract-
depends on your r squared method (not a good answer but the truest)